# When gestures sideslip back loading animation disappear, how to solve

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

Loading animation disappears when gestures sideslip back, how can I solve it?

Demo: https://github.com/Jinxiansen/JHUD

Screenshot:

[image]

Thanks!